# Why won't removeClass() and addClass() work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX call that will execute successfully, but when it reaches the `done()` section, it will print out my message "SUCCESS" but not change the classes of the button.

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: $(this).data("action"),
        data: {
            aId: $(this).data("a-id"),
            bId: $(this).data("b-id"),
            cId: $(this).data("c-id")
        }
    })
    .done(function () {
        console.log("SUCCESS");
        $(this).removeClass("btn-default");
        $(this).addClass("btn-success");
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("FAILURE");
        $(this).removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-danger");
    });
});
```

My *guess* is that it has to do with that fact that I'm not giving the function a ID of the button to act on, but to act on anything that is clicked that has the class "btn."  The page this originates from has a long list of buttons which is why they don't have IDs since the page would give them all the same ID.  I suppose I could append a number to the ID, but I would prefer not to do it that way.  It also doesn't explain why `$(this)` works in the rest of my AJAX function when retrieving values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$(this)` isn't the right `this`. Try caching the element.

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
    var $btn = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: $(this).data("action"),
        data: {
            aId: $(this).data("a-id"),
            bId: $(this).data("b-id"),
            cId: $(this).data("c-id")
        }
    })
    .done(function () {
        console.log("SUCCESS");
        $btn.removeClass("btn-default");
        $btn.addClass("btn-success");
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("FAILURE");
        $btn.removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-danger");
    });
});
```

Comment: Or use `context` ajax option: `context: this,`

Comment: Also, since you cache `$(this)`, you could use `$btn.data` aswell.

Comment: Suggestion: Chaining: `$btn.removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-success")`